# PostgreSQL Crosstab issues / "Return and SQL tuple descriptions are incompatible"

Tags: postgresql

Good afternoon, I am using POSTGRESql version 9.2 and I'm trying to use a crosstab function to transpose two columns on a table so that i can later join it to a different SELECT query.

I have installed the tablefunc extension.

However i keep getting this "Return and SQL tuple descriptions are incompatible" error which seems to be because of typecasts.
I don't need them to be a specific type.

My original SELECT query is this

```
SELECT inventoryid, ttype, tamount

FROM inventorytesting
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
inventoryid           ttype    tamount
2451530088940460        7       0.2
2451530088940460        2       0.5
2451530088940460        8       0.1
2451530088940460        1       15.7
8751530077940461        7       0.7
8751530077940461        2       0.2
8751530077940461        8       1.1
8751530077940461        1       19.2
```

and my goal is to get it like:

```
inventoryid          7      2       8       1
8751530077940461    0.7    0.2     1.1     19.2
2451530088940460    0.2    0.5     0.1     15.7
```

The 'ttype' field has 49 different values such as "7","2","8","1" which are fixed.
The 'tamount' field varies its values depending on the 'inventoryid' field but there will always be 49 of them, even if its value is zero.  It will never be "null".

I have tried a few variations that i could find in the internet which sum up to this:

```
SELECT *

FROM    crosstab (

    $$SELECT inventoryid, ttype, tamount
    FROM inventorytesting
    WHERE inventoryid = '2451530088940460'
    ORDER BY inventoryid, ttype$$
) 
AS ct("inventoryid" text,"ttype" smallint,"tamount" numeric)
```

The fieldtypes on the inventorytesting table are

```
select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'inventorytesting'
```

Results:

```
column_name    data_type
id             bigint
ttype          smallint
tamount        numeric
tunit          text
tlessthan      smallint
plantid        text
sessiontime    bigint
deleted        smallint
inventoryid    text
docdata        text
docname        text
labid          bigint
```

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a0f7615f489faa8550ea98c28180b8fe)

The resulting table definition has to contain the table structure you are expecting - the pivoted one - and not the structure of the given one:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    $$SELECT inventoryid, ttype, tamount
    FROM inventorytesting
    WHERE inventoryid = '2451530088940460'
    ORDER BY inventoryid, ttype$$
) 
AS ct("inventoryid" text,"type1" numeric,"type2" numeric,"type7" numeric,"type8" numeric)
```

---

Addionally there is no need to use the `crosstab` function. You can achieve a pivot by simply using the standard `CASE` function:

```
SELECT
    inventoryid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ttype = 1 THEN tamount END) AS type1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ttype = 2 THEN tamount END) AS type2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ttype = 7 THEN tamount END) AS type7,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ttype = 8 THEN tamount END) AS type8
FROM
    inventorytesting
GROUP BY 1
```

If you were on 9.4 or higher you could use the Postgres specific `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT
    inventoryid,
    SUM(tamount) FILTER (WHERE ttype = 1) AS type1,
    SUM(tamount) FILTER (WHERE ttype = 2) AS type2,
    SUM(tamount) FILTER (WHERE ttype = 7) AS type7,
    SUM(tamount) FILTER (WHERE ttype = 8) AS type8
FROM
    inventorytesting
GROUP BY 1
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=04549270fa0a0a6853262352b0f41f33)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the last piece of the crosstab, I was able to get it work with that in mind, however I enjoyed your solution to my issue using the "CASE" function as it was far more elegant. Once again thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

With the `crosstab`, you define the actual result table (basically the result of the pivot). The input query defines three columns which are then processed as:

1. grouping column result in the actual rows
2. the pivot columns
3. value for the pivot column

In your case, the `crosstab` therefore needs to be defined as:

```sql
ct(
    "inventoryid" text,
    "tamount_1" numeric,
    "tamount_2" numeric,
    "tamount_3" numeric,
    ...
)
```

The column header will then correlate to a certain value of column `ttype` in the order as defined by the inner query's `ORDER BY`.

The thing with `crosstab` is that missing values for `ttype` (e.g. some value returned for `4` but not for `3`), the resulting columns would be `1`, `2`, `4`, ... with `3` being missing. Here, you'd have to make sure (if you need consistent output) that your inner query returns at least a `NULL` row (e.g. via `LEFT JOIN`).

Comment: Thank you so much for expanding on what crosstab is expecting, requires. I was able to get the solution i needed with yours and "S-man"'s addition to CROSSTAB but I ended up omitting crosstab and going with the CASE function S-MAN suggested as it solved my issue in a more elegant manner. Once again, thank you.